# How to customize pagination in laravel to show a number of elements for each page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

my application basically generate reports for some users
I fetch the rows from the database
every row contains a 'name' and 'work time' and others...
every user has multiple rows with the same name but a different work time value
I calculated the total of the 'work time' in the blade depending on the next row if its the same name I 'll keep adding work time, if the next row is for another user then I will show the total for the current user and start calculating the total for the next user 
my problem is with pagination: 
at the end of each page, the rows of the same user do not appear all of it 
and my blade logic calculate only what appears on that page (see the picture)

[image]

notice here that other rows with the same name exist in the second page
and their total calculated separately 
[image]

is there is any way to tell the paginator to devise rows on a condition besides that number `->paginate(15+condition)` because I want all the rows for a specific user to stay on the same page.

this is the query:

```
$shifts = DB::table('driver_shifts')
        ->join('drivers','drivers.PermitNumber','=','driver_shifts.driver_badge_id')
        ->where ('driver_shifts.shift_start_time','>',$startDate)
        ->where ('driver_shifts.shift_start_time','<',$endDate)
        ->orderby('drivers.LastName')
        ->orderby('driver_shifts.shift_start_time')
        ->paginate(20)
        ->appends(request()->query());
```

this is the blade logic inside a table. Ps: I know it not a good practice but I coudn't find a better way to do it in the controller:

```
$total_time = 0.00;
$break_time = 0.00;
$work_time = 0.00;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($shifts); $i++)
{
    $break_time_item = $shifts[$i]->total_time - $shifts[$i]->work_time;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->FirstName . ' ' . $shifts[$i]->LastName . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->vehicle_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->shift_start_time . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->shift_end_time . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->total_time . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $break_time_item . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $shifts[$i]->work_time . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    //calculation totals for the current driver
    //dd($shifts[$i]->break_time);
    $total_time = $total_time + $shifts[$i]->total_time;
    $work_time = $work_time + $shifts[$i]->work_time;
    if (isset($shifts[$i + 1]))
    {
        if ($shifts[$i]->LastName !== $shifts[$i + 1]->LastName)
        {
            //calculating break time
            $break_time = $total_time - $work_time;
            //converting minutes to houres
            $total_time_hours = floor($total_time / 60);
            $total_time_min = $total_time - ($total_time_hours * 60);

            $work_time_hours = floor($work_time / 60);
            $work_time_min = $work_time - ($work_time_hours * 60);

            $break_time_hours = floor($break_time / 60);
            $break_time_min = $break_time - ($break_time_hours * 60);
            echo '<tr class="table-primary text-uppercase ">';
            echo '<td colspan="4">' . $shifts[$i]->FirstName . ' ' . $shifts[$i]->LastName . ' TOTAL ' . '</td>';

            if ($total_time_hours == 0 && $total_time_min == 0)
            {
                echo '<td>-</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>' . $total_time_hours . "h:" . $total_time_min . "min" . '</td>';
            }

            if ($break_time_hours == 0 && $break_time_min == 0)
            {
                echo '<td>-</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>' . $break_time_hours . "h:" . $break_time_min . "min" . '</td>';
            }

            if ($work_time_hours == 0 && $work_time_min == 0)
            {
                echo '<td>-</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>' . $work_time_hours . "h:" . $work_time_min . "min" . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            $total_time = 0;
            $break_time = 0;
            $work_time = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not change your query to group by user so that each result shows the total per user, and then allow your user to click the rows to expand them (or use a dialog) to show details (via AJAX)? This way pagination is simple.

Comment: your idea is great but actually, the client who wants this application ask me to show it this way

Comment: Why not re-query for each user and inject the results into your table? So the page counter would still reflect users, but the results for each user would be included in the page? If you like this approach I can post some pseudo code as an answer.

Comment: thank you I already found another solution that worked for me
it was by turning the collection retrieved into an array and do the calculation on the array and injecting the new rows into that array before passing it into the view 
and for the pagination, I made my own paginator inspiring from this post: https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-pagination-array/